# PHP stops rendering page somewhat arbitrarily

Tags: php, apache, windows-xp, xampp

I've spent all morning trying to find an answer to this, to no avail. I'm working on a website, and I set up a small test server to make changes on. When I loaded the page I had made a few changes to, I noticed that the page stopped short. I reloaded the page, and it stopped at a different place. I reloaded again and again, and noticed three or four places that it stopped at, but couldn't predict where it would stop. The page itself is included from the page with the logic in it, is included when the page isn't POSTed to. I made a small page page containing only a `phpinfo();`, and the same problem exists as well. It stops at seemingly random places in the tables produced.

Has anyone else ever had this problem, and if so, how did you get rid of it?

Setup:

- Windows XP (Test Server)
- XAMPP

  - PHP 5.2.9
  - Apache 2.2.11

The only change I made to the server was pointing the document root at a different folder in the `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Probably somewhat obvious, but have you checked the apache/php error logs?  Also, if you revert the change you made to httpd.conf, does the behavior stop?

Comment: Try making sure display_errors is on in your php.ini file, so you can see any errors.  Sometimes it is off by default.

Comment: Take a look at your apache access log.  Apache records the number of bytes sent -- is it the same every time?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your script is running out of 
1) Memory
2) Max execution time

Check those constants in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the apache and php server logs.
If you have it crash on you when only calling phpinfo() and nothing else, then it most likely is somekind of conflict (not your code).

Post your logs here if you need more help.

Comment: I'm not sure what I even did, but the problem disappeared. I'll look over the logs when I have access to the server again, and see if I can find anything out of the ordinary. Thanks anyways!